# Accessibility ARIA issues with react-select

Tags: autocomplete, accessibility, react-select, wai-aria

We are using react-select component in one of our projects and trying to resolve accessibility issues. Right now, there is no way to provide the required aria attributes to the input element which has the aria-autocomplete="list" attribute.

https://www.digitala11y.com/aria-autocomplete-properties/

Above is the reference link to what we are trying to achieve. Below is the short story from the above link.

```
If an element has aria-autocomplete set to list or both, authors MUST ensure both of the following conditions are met:

The element has a value specified for aria-controls that refers to the element that contains the collection of suggested values.
Either the element or a containing element with role combobox has a value for aria-haspopup that matches the role of the element that contains the collection of suggested values.
```

I opened a PR to add the ability to add ARIA properties to the input element. https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/pull/4132

But I wanted to check if I'm missing something if anyone has already worked on this. Please let me know if you need any other details.